# Create newdocument with saveAs2 fails

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a new document from another document, however it fails:

[image]

```
Set createDocOutDocument = createDocOutDocument.SaveAs(fileName:=docOutname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SaveAs` doesn't return anything, and in any case you'd just be getting a reference to the same document already referenced by `createDocOutDocument`

All you need here is:

```
createDocOutDocument.SaveAs(fileName:=docOutname)
```

Comment: so if the document was called a.doc then `createDocOutDocument.SaveAs(fileName:="b.docx")` and then run `createDocOutDocument.fullname` will then return b.docx right?